# Lock windows workstation using Python

Tags: python, windows

Is there a way to lock the PC from a Python script on Windows?

I do not want to implement some kind of locking on my own - I'd like to use the same lock screen that's also used when the user presses <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or locks the machine via the start menu.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This can be done with the [`LockWorkStation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from *user32.dll*:

> This function has the same result as pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del and clicking Lock Workstation.

In Python it can be called using using the ctypes/windll FFI from the Python stdlib:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
```

Comment: @Mandelbrotter How is that comment supposed to be useful? I mentioned in my original question that WIN+L locks the desktop, and my question was obviously about doing it programmatically...

Answer (score 1):

A good solution that makes us avoid using Libraries/DLL files is to use the command prompet/ power shell.
try running this command in your cmd `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation`....**The PC is Locked!!**
so we can use subprocess to run this command like this:

```
    import subprocess
    cmd='rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation'
    subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Comment: I think that's pretty messy. also, you shouldn't use `shell=True` here - there's absolutely no need for this here.

Comment: I think calling rundll from code that is able to call dll functions directly is messy. Also, `subprocess.call()` should ideally be called with an array (command and args) instead of a string.

Comment: i think you are right,but my code above works well with subprocess

Answer (score -1):

You can use the OS Library which is already in Python:

```
import os
os.system("rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation")
```