# Detect when computer is unlocked Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I have used [this excellent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733441/lock-windows-workstation-using-python#20733443) to lock a windows computer; that part works fine.  What I would like to do, however, is detect when the computer is then unlocked and then proceed with my program.  I have done a fair bit of research on the web to find a way to do this, but I haven't seen any way for python to detect a change in the computer status (ie when the computer is logged on again or unlocked).  **Is it possible in python to detect when the Windows machine is *unlocked or logged on to*?**  Note I am working with python 2.7.6 and on Windows 7.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a script in http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/see_if_my_workstation_is_locked.html

```
import time
import ctypes

user32 = ctypes.windll.User32
OpenDesktop = user32.OpenDesktopA
SwitchDesktop = user32.SwitchDesktop
DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x0100

user32.LockWorkStation ()
#
# Slight pause to overcome what appears to
# be a grace period during which a switch
# *will* succeed.
#
time.sleep (1.0)

while 1:
  hDesktop = OpenDesktop ("default", 0, False, DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP)
  result = SwitchDesktop (hDesktop)
  if result:
    print "Unlocked"
    break
  else:
    print time.asctime (), "still locked"
    time.sleep (2)
```

Comment: allways says "locked" (on my windows10)