# Check if the Windows screen is locked

Tags: python, windows

Is there a way to auto-check if the current user locked his PC? (usually activated by `Win+L`). One hacky method I see is somehow catch all key combinations, but then the question is how to know that the user has returned?

Maybe there is some flag that can be accessed through python or windows terminal?

EDIT: I tried the code from here: [Detect when computer is unlocked Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599462/detect-when-computer-is-unlocked-windows)

It detects when screen is locked, but not when it's unlocked, it continues to write "Screen is still locked" indefinitely. So what can be the problem? I have Python 3.4, 64-bit Win7.

EDIT2: Actually the `result` is always `0` for me, even without any locking, so in fact it doesn't detect anything.

```
import ctypes

user32 = ctypes.windll.User32
OpenDesktop = user32.OpenDesktopA
SwitchDesktop = user32.SwitchDesktop
DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x0100

hDesktop = OpenDesktop ("default", 0, False, DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP)
result = SwitchDesktop (hDesktop)

print(result)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when computer is unlocked Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599462/detect-when-computer-is-unlocked-windows)

Comment: I tried, and it works only partially.

Comment: This code won't work in Python 3 because you're passing unicode to the (all-but-deprecated and definitely to be avoided) [A]NSI API `OpenDesktopA` instead of the [W]ide-character API `OpenDesktopW`. It's also not setting `restype` and `argtypes`, so it could easily crash Python. It's not handling errors. It's leaking a handle. It's possibly modifying the current input desktop as a side effect. It's using `ctypes.windll`, which is vulnerable to inter-library conflicts, instead of `ctypes.WinDLL`, and thus also not using `use_last_error=True` to protect the thread's last error value.

Comment: Thanks, using OpenDesktopW made it work.

Comment: Techniques that depend on behavior of the secure desktop, such as this one, are unreliable in Windows 10. When the work station is locked, e.g. via `LockWorkStation`, it's not immediately set to the secure desktop. You have to click to switch to the secure desktop (I don't know why), which is where you're prompted for credentials. It's better to directly query the terminal services API to check whether the session is locked -- a query that's supported in Windows 7 and later.

Answer (score -2):

Open comp mgmt, open remote console, input computer name
Once connected to remote console check security logs

Note: you can set a base computer to receive log files of your choice, enabling you to automatically see when a user logs on/off/lock/unlocks