# Disable Alt+Tab Combination on Tkinter App

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can i disable Alt+Tab combination, especially tab on my Tkinter App.
I disabled Alt and F4 with *-* return "break" *-* but i can't disable Tab key with it.

Comment: you want the user to be locked out of using the `alt-tab` keyboard shortcut?  That seems like an unnecessarily limiting feature, could you explain why you want to accomplish this?

Comment: Also note that there are [lots of ways to switch between open apps](http://www.pcworld.com/article/238080/Windows.html) in windows so if your goal is to completely lock the user into your application you are out of luck.

Comment: Because this is a screen lock. It locks up the screen, you enter the password, then open the screen. Logic of the program is like this.

Comment: I very much doubt it is possible to completely lock a user into a single application, and I believe that is intended by design.  Why can't you [use the lock screen built into windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733441/lock-windows-workstation-using-python)?

Comment: If you want to lock the screen, try doing a global grab. That will prevent anything other than your window from getting keypress events. While I haven't tried it, I suspect it will also grab alt-tab.About the only thing it won't grab are low-level interrupts like ctrl-alt-del.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter provides no option for this. Alt-tab is intercepted before tkinter ever sees it. If you want to do this, you'll have to find some platform-specific hooks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyHook
import pygame

# create a keyboard hook
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    

    
    if event.Key.lower() in ['tab','alt']#Keys to block:
        return False    # block these keys
    
    else:
        # return True to pass the event to other handlers
        return True

# create a hook manager
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
# watch for all keyboard events
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
# set the hook
hm.HookKeyboard()

# initialize pygame and start the game loop
pygame.init()

while(1):
    pygame.event.pump()
```

To install pyhook
First install pygame

```
pip install pygame
```

and pyhook from:
this link:

> [PyHook](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/)