# Invoking the lock screen using python

Tags: python, ubuntu, authentication, lockscreen

How can I bring up the lock screen from within a python app? I would like the application to do that for me instead of pressing the Ctrl-Alt-L separately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Ubuntu:

```
os.popen('gnome-screensaver-command --lock')
```

([Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457204/how-can-i-lock-the-screen-using-the-new-lockscreen-from-the-command-line/492963))

For Windows:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733441/lock-windows-workstation-using-python#20733443))

Comment: what if gnome is not install, e.g if xfce is install what to do then?